# colored 100% barplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Ia am completly new to R and just absolved the introduction from edX. Unfortunately it doesn't teach anything about ggplot2, what i want to use for my graphs in my thesis. I want to get 100% bar plots with different colours and if possible the value in the according bar. my data looks like this:

```
Concentration,Percentage,Phenotype
Control,0.933333333,0
Control,0.014814815,1
Control,0.022222222,2
Control,0.02962963,3
0.002,0.918181818,0
0.002,0.018181818,1
0.002,0.018181818,2
0.002,0.045454545,3
0.02,0.930434783,0
0.02,0.017391304,1
0.02,0.017391304,2
0.02,0.034782609,3
0.2,0.928571429,0
0.2,0.032467532,1
0.2,0.012987013,2
0.2,0.025974026,3
2,0.859813084,0
2,0.028037383,1
2,0.046728972,2
2,0.065420561,3
```

and the code i used is this:

```
ggplot(Inj, aes(x=Concentration, y=Percentage, fill=Phenotype))+geom_bar(stat='identity',color='black')
```

The resulting graph looks like that:

[image]

how can i change the color of the different bars and get the %-values in the bars?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use `scale_x_discrete` to re-order the factors manually like this:

```
ggplot(Inj, aes(x=Concentration, y=Percentage, fill=Phenotype)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity',color='black') +
  scale_fill_grey(start = .4, end = .9) + 
  theme_bw()+ylab("Distribution") + 
  xlab("Contentration [mg/ml]") + 
  ggtitle("Dose-respond analysis") +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=10, face="bold")) +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="white",
                                   size=0.5, linetype="solid", 
                                   colour ="black")) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c('Control','0.002', '0.02', '0.2', '2'),
                   labels=c('Control\n(N=000)',
                            '0.002\n(N=000)', 
                            '0.02\n(N=000)', 
                            '0.2\n(N=000)', 
                            '2\n(N=000)'))
```

I added the `labels` part to `scale_x_discrete` in response to your question in the comments below. You just need to update the N values. Notice that I put `\n` in each label in order to force the label text on to two lines so it wouldn't be jumbled. Just remove the `\n` if you'd prefer it to be on a single line.

Comment: Ok thanks! one last thing would be to label every bar with the number of observed individuals. like n=158 or something like that for control, n=145 for 0.002 and so on. is that possible? only thing i found on the internet is to add the actual value of a bar, but i want to label every single bar individually.

Comment: Just edited the answer to include a solution to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the colors controllable by making your fill variable a factor.  Then you can manually adjust the colors like this

```
ggplot(Inj, aes(x=Concentration, y=Percentage, fill=factor(Phenotype)))+geom_bar(stat='identity',color='black') +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "yellow", "pink"))
```

[image]

I don't recommend putting the values over the colors as they won't be visible for the very small values.  I would use another way to visualize the data.